# Words to describe attached items

Tags: single-word-requests

We have an object A that is physically attached to object B. 
What can we call object A? I would have expected to be able to use "attachee", but this is not in the dictionary, or "attaché", but this seems to only apply to a member of an embassy.
What can we call object B? Is there a word for "attached to"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is **Words to describe attached items**

The answer to this is an **attachment** However, I am not sure if this is the word you are looking for.

**Accessory** or **Addition** could also be used in this context.

​
**Attachment** noun (PART) an extra piece of equipment that can be added to a machine: [C.E.D](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/attachment)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you also help me find the answer to the question "an attachment is attached to ?"

Comment: @Dan. I think you will need to give me some more information about the context to be used. I do not know if these are useful but here are some examples Attachment A can be fitted here. Attachment B can only be fitted on Printers made after 1786... Attachment c is fitted in the locating holes at the rear of the Coffee Grinder etc. The brush head attachment for cleaning sofa's and curtains can be found under the top cover of  the vacuum cleaner.

Comment: We're developing a Gantt chart rendering engine. We use the concepts of "milestones" and "tasks". One feature we support is to "attach" a milestone to a task, meaning the milestone is rendered on the task shape instead of floating independently in the chart. We use the phrase "Milestone M1 is attached to task T1
"

Comment: @Dan Ah this is easy; MS Project "Links" Milestones and tasks. Yes project related milestones need to be linked to all relevant tasks. Although independent milestones like customer utilities  have to remain floating.

Comment: Our team has already started using the term "attached", it will be difficult to switch to "linked". Do you think you can suggest the word for "a task having a milestone attached (linked)"?

Comment: @Dan; Primary Task. as its must be important to be directly linked to a milestone. Tasked linked to tasks could be secondary tasks. Non linked tasks could be independent or standalone tasks.